# SQL query advice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been having trouble coming up with a proper query to handle this situation in SQL Server.

There are two tables, Warehouse and Transfer:

Warehouse

- wh_id(PK)
- wh_name

Transfer

- transfer_id(PK)
- transfer_from(FK)
- transfer_to (FK)

I need a query to return:

- transfer_id
- transfer_from - Name, not id
- transfer_to - Name, not id

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT T.transfer_id, WH.wh_name, T.transfer_to
FROM transfer AS T INNER JOIN warehouse AS WH
ON T.transfer_from = WH.wh_id
```

This only gives the name for the transfer_from not the transfer_to. I've had a need for a similar query but my level of SQL expertise is low and I just don't know how to approach this problem. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to join the table `warehouse` twice because you need to get the equivalent name fro two columsn in your `transfer` table.

```
SELECT  a.transfer_ID,
        b.wh_name AS from_name,
        c.wh_name AS to_Name
FROM        transfer a
            INNER JOIN warehouse b
                ON a.transfer_from = b.wh_id
            INNER JOIN warehouse c
                ON a.transfer_to = c.wh_id
```

Comment: change the second b.wh_name as to_Name to c.wh_name As to_Name. So the answer should be like this        SELECT  a.transfer_ID,
        b.wh_name AS from_name,
        c.wh_name AS to_Name
FROM        transfer a
            INNER JOIN warehouse b
                ON a.transfer_from = b.wh_id
            INNER JOIN warehouse c
                ON a.transfer_to = c.wh_id

Comment: @JohnWoo Thanks, this was very clear and will help me greatly in the future. Never thought to do multiple joins but now that you've shown me it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tr.transfer_id, wh_from.wh_name, wh_from.wh_name
from transfer tr, warehouse wh_from, warehouse wh_to
where tr.transfer_From = wh_From.wh_id
and tr.transfer_to = wh_to.wh_id
```

Comment: Argh! Attack of the killer `,` !!! Seriously though, isn't 20+ years long enough for `ANSI-92` standard to be, umm, standard? Not to mention that most RDBMS have now deprecated this notation?

Comment: As long as oracle supports it, I ansi-92 is nothing more than a standard ;-)

Comment: If you are an Oracle fan, why not take Oracle's advice? `Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax...` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm *[I'm sure that you're **not** recommending mixing syntax for different circumstances?]*

Comment: its not about "fan" or not. Its just about code readability...This version is just easier to read and quicker to write... 180 vs 280 characters in examples above. And this is just one short query with 3 tables.

Comment: If you read the debate on this notation, having all the joins in the `WHERE` clause is not considered `easier to read`, infact it is more universally considered that having the `ON` clause makes the implicit nature of the join condition significantly easier to read.  Additionally, the idea of `this is just one quick query` means that you ***are*** supporting the idea of different notation for different circumstances - And mixing of styles, notation, and standards, is almost universally accepted as a software anti-pattern.  It's a short term choice that builds up technical debt.